# how to do tasks in order in actionlistener

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

i want to do tasks in particular order in actionlistener. in my code i wish to display loading icon on action while the main task on the button is performed.however when i press d button everything is done at same time.. i want that the JLabel img should display my image before performing the task of database connection..here is my code

```
take.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
       img.setIcon(image);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                 cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                 SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                 String formatted = format1.format(cal.getTime());
       String dname = (String)doclist.getSelectedItem();
        try{
            db.connect();

    rs=db.stmt.executeQuery("Select * from table4 where name='"+dname+"'");
          rs.next();
             final String id=rs.getString("dr_id");
             String mst=rs.getString("mor_start");
             String est=rs.getString("eve_start");
             int mmax=rs.getInt("mor_max");
             int emax=rs.getInt("eve_max");
             int mava=rs.getInt("mor_ava");
             int eava=rs.getInt("eve_ava");
          }});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `SwingWorker`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `SwingWorker` as @camickr says. Here you have a complete [example](http://www.javacreed.com/swing-worker-example/). The idea is that you run some process in another background thread not in the same thread as the GUI. The gui stuff runs in the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

Here you have an example:

```
class Worker extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {

   private JLabel labelToUpdate;
   private final String dname;    


    public Worker(JLabel label, String dname){
         super();
         this.labelToUpdate=label;
         this.dname=dname;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doInBackground() throws Exception {
       //here you make heavy task this is running in another thread not in EDT                 
       //  you connect to the db and make the query you can call
       // publish("connectin to the db") and this will call process

       // Connection con = ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(String chunk : chunks){
           sb.append(chunk).append("\n");
        }
          labelToUpdate.setText(sb.toString());        
    }

   //Executed on the Event Dispatch Thread after the doInBackground method is finished
   @Override
   protected void done(){
      labelToUpdate.setIcon(null);
   }
}
```

And in the actionListener

```
take.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
          String dname = (String)doclist.getSelectedItem();
          SwingWorker worker = new Worker(label,dname);
          label.setIcon(image);
          worker.execute();  
    }
);
```

Comment: can u be more specific using my example plss.. it would be very helpfull

Comment: and how to i pass arguments like dname and many other which are required to execute query in db

Comment: @user2984132 You can make a wrapper class having that as attributes or make them attributes for the swingWorker and pass it by constructor or by setter as i did with the label ;), let me know if you don't understand my point

Comment: please explain it using my example.. i am confused.. tell me what to do at both sides

Comment: @user2984132, This is why I don't spoon feed the answers. The OP doesn't learn anything and they keep asking questions. There are plenty of example using a SwingWorker, both in the tutorial and in the forum. Don't expect people to write the code for you. Post your code that shows what you have attempted to do. Then maybe we can help fix the problem. This is called a `SSCCE`.

Comment: @camickr sorry i though i was clear answering with example but OP didn't understand me.

Comment: i have already given my code.. what i am trying to do is setting a loading image while my application does updation and insertion part in db.. but when i write the queries in worker class it cannot find many symcols becoz they are used in the current class..

Comment: @user2984132 You can pass them to the worker class with setter or with the constructor injection. ;), as i did in example with `label`

Comment: i tried that.. but for example i passed dname through constructor but still it could not be read in doinBackground method..:(

Comment: @user2984132 i edit answer and i put `dname` property, hope it helps!

Comment: @user2984132, `i have already given my code.. ` - no you haven't. The suggestion was to use a SwingWorker. You have NOT posted the code showing your attempt at using a SwingWorker. You are expecting someone to spoon feed the code to you.